# How to measure change in efficiency of AC condenser unit

Tags: hvac

I will be building from scratch an enclosure for the outdoor condenser unit of our 12+ year old central AC system.  For looks and canine pee pee.  I'm sure I can address the later, but not certain about the former since a google image search turns up nothing but uglies.  Nonetheless.  Anyway, nebulously speaking, it should be as small as possible without restricting the air flow too much.

I'm concerned about reduced service life of the system.  I'm not concerned about an utility bill increase, or lengthened time to cool down the house.  We aren't willing to pay the several hundred dollars it would fear it would cost to have it moved to a new location where looks wouldn't matter.

After building a quick mock up of an initial design, I'd like to measure the reduction in efficiency, or how much extra work it is causing.

Two approaches come to mind.  Measure electrical usage for 15 minute runs with and without the enclosure, using the house electric meter. Measure the temperatures of the refrigerant lines using a hardware store thermometer.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Most A/C units only have one speed.  They will draw standard current at that speed.  What will vary is how long they run per cycle.  But that will also vary by weather, so not useful for A/B comparison.

Comment: you need to calculate a duty cycle with and without.  I would raise the house to 80F, then time how long it takes to pull it down to 75, with and without your mod. do each cycle twice and average to remove uncertainty.